# ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running Hadoop-1.2.1 and HBase-0.94.11 in a pseudo-distributed mode.

Due to power failure Hadoop and HBase set up went down.Next time when I restarted my machine and the pseudo-distribution set up, HBase stopped working with the following errors on HBase shell:

```
13/11/27 13:53:27 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
13/11/27 13:53:27 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ClusterId.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.getId(ClusterId.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.hasId(ClusterId.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.ensureZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Following are the processes :

```
hduser@user-ubuntu:~$ jps
16914 NameNode
19955 Jps
29460 Main
17728 TaskTracker
19776 HMaster
17490 JobTracker
17392 SecondaryNameNode
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Zookeeper process is running (your jps listing doesn't show an entry for QuorumPeerMain)? The jps stack may not show all java processes running - try using a `ps axww | grep QuorumPeerMain`.

If your zookeeper refuses to start, check its logs to see if there are some stack trace clues

Comment: i ran the command and below is the output:
hduser@user-ubuntu:~$ ps axww | grep QuorumPeerMain
15527 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto QuorumPeerMain

Comment: So zookeeper isn't running (that grep match is the grep cmd itself) - i suggest you stop your cluster services, start zookeeper, the the remaining hadoop and hbase services

Comment: How to restart `Zookeeper` again?

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward the zookeeper quorum process is not running - if it has been, there'd have been another java process:

```
hduser@user-ubuntu:~$ jps
16914 NameNode
19955 Jps
29460 Main
17728 TaskTracker
19776 HMaster
17490 JobTracker
17392 SecondaryNameNode
```

**`xxxxx HQuorumPeer`**

[Zookeeper](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html) is required for HBase cluster - as it manages it.

---

**Possible solutions**:
By default HBase manages zookeeper itself i.e. starting and stopping the zookeeper quorum (the cluster of zookeeper nodes) - to verify the settings  look into the file conf/hbase-evn.sh (in your hbase directory) there must be a line:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Basically tells HBase whether it should manage its own instance of Zookeeper or not. In case it is set to `false`, edit to `true`.

Also verify the HBase conf at `conf/hbase-site.xml`,

The minimum conf that should work for pseudo-distributed mode is:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>   
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/<yourusername>/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Now stop the HBase, if it's been running:

```
$ ./bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

make the neccessary changes and start it again:

```
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

---

Answers you may find helpful:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674331/hbase-error-zookeeper-exists-failed-after-3-retiries/36591944#36591944)   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969677/stand-alone-hbase-on-local-file-system-getting-zookeeper-error/36591479#36591479)