# Stand alone HBase on local file system getting zookeeper error?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Hi guys I am trying to follow the [quick start of HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html) and start an HBase on the local file system( without using HDFS ) However when I start the shell using ./hbase shell and type "status" I get zookeeper error ?!

```
hbase(main):001:0> status
14/01/07 12:44:48 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
14/01/07 12:44:48 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid

//......... ect .....
```

Here is my config file ( hbase-site.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2010 The Apache Software Foundation
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->
<configuration>


<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/adio/workspace/hadoop/hbase/directories/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/adio/workspace/hadoop/hbase/directories/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
      For example, "host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com".
      By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes
      of operation. For a fully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full
      list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.sh
      this is the list of servers which we will start/stop ZooKeeper on.
      </description>
 </property>

<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
</property>



<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
      <value>1000</value>
      <description>
      </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here (in your conf - `conf/hbase-site.xml`):

```
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
```

As the error "**ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries**" indicates there is some problem with your  `zookeeper.quorum` directive. Or Before staring the HBase shell you can verify if the ZKQuorum is up, using:

```
$ jps
```

the command will list all the java processes on the machine i.e. the probable output has to be:

```
62019 Jps
61098 HMaster        
61233 HRegionServer     
61003 HQuorumPeer
```

---

**Solution**:

In your HBase directory, first stop the HBase:

```
$ ./bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

If you're trying to work out the 'standalone HBase' example - stick to the minimum conf provided in the example:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/adio/workspace/hadoop/hbase/directories/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/adio/workspace/hadoop/hbase/directories/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

i.e. your `conf/hbase-site.xml` should have the above content.

Once set, now start the HBase again:

```
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your zookeeper quorum name must be the hostname of your machine and must also be present in the /etc/hosts file. Try restarting the network after this.