# Hbase error zookeeper exists failed after 3 retiries

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using HBASE 0.94.8 standalone mode in Ubuntu. Its working fine i am able to do every operations in Hbase-shell. But after i logged of my system its giving following error

```
15/07/28 15:10:30 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
15/07/28 15:10:30 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x14ed40513350009 Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RootRegionTracker.waitRootRegionLocation(RootRegionTracker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:998)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:998)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:900)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:857)
```

Yes sure i have searched a lot. I have found some information [ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239072/zookeeper-exists-failed-after-3-retries). May be this error is because **zookeeper** is stopped. But i don't know to to restart it again. I tried to start `Hbase` and `thrift` again but still this is issue.

This command `ps axww | grep QuorumPeerMain` gives me following output:

```
 6162 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto QuorumPeerMain
```

Hbase starts working if i restart my system. But i want proper solution.

---

**Temporary solution**

with following command i grep this process of HBASE:

```
ps -fe grep | hbase
```

and then kill all process of HBASE :

```
kill -9 4555//assuming 4555 is process id of hbase
```

Then restarted hbase with sudo and thrift and it start working but i want permanent solution. Because if i am using HBASE in server (means not local machine) i can't restart HBASE everytime.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue**:

**Hbase error zookeeper exists failed after 3 retiries**
clearly indicates that zookeeper quorum is not running - most probable cause can be some inconsistency with your zookeeper.quorum setting in `conf/hbase-site.xml`, the minimal has to be:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/testuser/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/testuser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

In the next section it is succinctly mentioned why zookeeper is required and how can one verify if it's running.

---

**An overview**:

Pre-assuming from your text (standalone setup) - you're mixing things up.
Zookeeper in simple words manages HBase, and is a must requirement.

By default HBase itself handles zookeeper setup, start-stop (though one can change) - to verify look into the file `conf/hbase-evn.sh` (in your hbase directory) there must be a line:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Basically tells HBase whether it should manage its own instance of Zookeeper or not. In case it is set to `false`, edit to `true`.

Now for verification there's a helpful command (forget about the `ps` and then `grep`):

```
$ jps
```

the command will list all the java processes (HBase is itself a Java application) on the machine i.e. the probable output has to be (for a minimal standalone HBase setup):

```
62019 Jps
61098 HMaster        
61233 HRegionServer     
61003 HQuorumPeer
```

Don't just kill the HBase process, instead use the start-stop utility:

```
$ ./bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

make the neccessary changes and start it again:

```
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

**P.S.** I could have misinterpreted your question (completely), do let me know in the comments I'll get back to you again and get the solution right - for the upcoming SO visitors.

Comment: To add to the above solution: the value for hbase.rootdir should exist. Facing the same issue, setting hbase.rootdir to hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase worked for me well after creating the folder in HDFS. However, the default directory after installing hbase didn't work for me as it didn't exist already.

Comment: So one has just to add the few lines in `conf/hbase-site.xml` and this is it ? Shouldn't we create some directories first ?

Answer (score 3):

When you look into the log files you will find that zookeeper is unable to connect with a port. For example, `543210`. That simply means
you have previously installed Hadoop on your machine, so hbase tries to lookup the previous hadoop installation's zookeeper. Please rename your existing hadoop setup or remove completely hadoop from your system. (But note that zookeeper seems to leave things around even after a deletion.)

- Rename hadoop installation folder
- Remove entry from .bashrc file
- Restart computer

Comment: I have a requirement to have both `hadoop` and `hbase` installed on the same machine as given in here [http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#standalone.over.hdfs]. I have installed `hadoop` first and now I am trying to install `hbase` and getting the above error. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is not related to `hbase` or `zookeeper`. It is a system setting issue.

I've got the same issue after my Mac OS X update.

It turned out that DNS settings were changed by the update. I saw that in hbase logs:

```
2017-06-09 11:40:18,454 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:143)
[SKIP]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2432)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:92)
```

After removing DNS settings in `hbase-site.xml` the issue dissipeared:

```
  <!--property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property-->
```

Comment: This works! Note that you need to make doubly sure no hbase processes are running before restarting.

Answer (score 1):

I've got almost the same error "ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 retries". It was caused by running ./start-hbase.sh without having permissions to connect to the port 2181. The solution turned out to be really simple:

```
sudo ./start-hbase.sh
```

I've used the same configuration of hbase-site.xml as it is in Nabeel Ahmed's post.

Answer (score 0):

If its only starting zookeeper, [this](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_InstallingSingleMode) should help you. I hope you are aware that zookeeper should be up and running before we start hbase.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working with sudo command

```
hbase/bin$sudo ./start-habase.sh
```